How would I approach representing a "Thin-Walled" maze?

is representative of the type of maze I want to make. The walls don't occupy spaces, they just prevent you from moving between them. Since the walls aren't 2d tiles I don't think I'd use a 2d boolean array to represent it. I am not asking for help with how to generate a maze, just how to represent one of this type.

Use numbers between 0 and 15 for each tile, where each of the bits represents a wall in the north, east, south or west direction, if the bit is set to 1, and no wall if the bit is 0

What do you use the represent the "tiles".  It looks like you can have a wall between two tiles, maybe your tiles should have a field to represent the walls. enum Wall{ solid, none}  Then your tile would have class Tile{ Wall north = Wall.solid; ... Or you could use an array. On a single int and pack the bits. 0 none, 1 north, 2, east, 4 south, 8 west.(that is what the previous comment is suggesting.)

I have ended up going with 2 arrays, a (W+1)(H) array for vertical walls, and a (W)(H+1) array for horizontal walls. With this I can plug in a cell's coordinates and coordinates + 1 to get their adjacent walls. Now, I have one central place to get and set my wall data, so I don't worry about modifying cells stored wall values, like I would with the method described by QBrute & matt. I also think this is far more intuitive to use than having to abstract the maze into a thick walled one.

An extra bit on the comments by QBrute and matt.
Marking walls on the 4 sides of a tile has the problem of consistency. For example if you have 2 horizontal tiles next to each other, one needs a wall on the right, the other a wall on the left, and there's a problem if this goes out of sync.
You can avoid this potential inconsistency by marking only 2 walls per tile (e.g. south/bottom and east/right) and have row and column 0 out of bounds for the player, but these are needed to hold the top most and left most walls.

I've found that it's pretty convenient for a WxH maze to use a (W+1)x(2H+1) matrix of Booleans.
The even numbered rows (starting at zero) are for horizontal walls, and the odd-numbered rows are for vertical walls.

Note that this type of maze can be mapped to a maze where walls are not thin, i.e. they consist of wall-cells. The difference is that when you walk through the maze, you always can take two steps at a time, in the same direction, but besides this double-step, it is the same maze.
For instance, the maze you presented in the question can be mapped to this one:

